# loop and raw_input simultaneously?

Tags: python

I'm making a program that listens for commands both from a looping raw_input and repeatedly checking a file for updates. Is there a way to do this? Basically, there's a loop with a `time.sleep(1)` for checking the file, and a while loop with `raw_input`. Multiprocessing doesn't seem to be what I need.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `time.sleep` in this situation

Comment: @JoelCornett I believe the op is checking a file for updates, then calling time.sleep(1), then checking the file again.  I could be wrong.

Comment: ever heard of [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html)?

Comment: I agree,  you want to use threading.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty correct. I want to be able to run a function with both the input, and another application, which would edit the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the answer is "threading". Seems promising.